# How do I static assert numeric_limits::max()?

Tags: c++

Basically, I want to do this:

```
// error: function call is not allowed in a constant expression:
static_assert(
  std::numeric_limits<Volume>::max() > 123456, 
  "Volume data type too small"
  );
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: what's type of volume?

Comment: That should compile, the function is a `constexpr`. What is `Volume` and what compiler are you using (incl. version)?

Comment: @billz It's derived from a primitive, that's all I know.

Comment: @juanchopanza you're right - VC++ bug maybe.. thanks..

Comment: @ausairman [This works for me](http://ideone.com/AVGr4b) both with IDEone (gcc 4.3+ AFAIK) and on OS X 10.7 with clang++ 3.2.

Comment: It could be that they haven't implemented the `numeric_limits` stuff as `constexpr` yet. It wasn't `constepxr` in C++03, for obvious reasons.

Comment: MSVC doesn't have constexpr implemented yet. Partially it should be implemented in MSVC 2013 CTP this year. At least they promised it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use MSVC, for now you cannot. The latest MSVC from toolset v.14 still defines `std::numeric_limits::max()` without `constexpr`